# Remove checklisted li from ol

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove a checked item from a list (by pressing the button 'removeTask') but it only removes the checkbox, leaving the li text.

```
$("#removeTask").click(
  function(){
    $("#taskchecklist li").find(":checked").remove();
  }
);
```

Here is the htlm code:

```
          <ol id="taskchecklist">             
            <li id="task0"><input type="checkbox"> Feed the cat<br></li>
            <li id="task1"><input type="checkbox"> Make dinner for three<br></li>
            <li id="task2"><input type="checkbox"> Take a shower<br></li>
            <li id="task3"><input type="checkbox"> Turn on spotify<br></li>
          </ol>
        Add new task: <input id="taskAdded" type="text"> <button id="addTask">Add</button><br>
        <button id="removeTask">Remove finished tasks</button>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [:has selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

```
$("#taskchecklist li:has(input:checked)").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

The find(":checked") is selecting the input element. Select it's parent to remove the list item

```
$("#taskchecklist li").find(":checked").parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parent of checked input

```
$("#taskchecklist input:checked").parent('li').remove();
```